# input:read-only css property execute without dom shows read only input field. Read only not declared button show how execute from CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

input:read-only css property execute without dom shows read only input field. Read only not declared for any of the input field but its execute from css. how to check what it causing ?

```
        <input class="k-button-billing-viewonly" style="height:auto; margin-top:5px;" type="submit" value="View Collections Information" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to ask that you are not able to type in this input field and you think that some `CSS` is adding the read-only property to the input field?
If this is what you want to ask then I think

```
 <input class="k-button-billing-viewonly" style="height:auto; margin-top:5px;" type="submit" value="View Collections Information" autocomplete="off">
```

in the input field above you need to remove the `type="submit"` property.

It would look like

```
<input class="k-button-billing-viewonly" style="height:auto; margin-top:5px;" value="View Collections Information" autocomplete="off">
```

Now you can type in the input field if that is what you needed.

and instead of `type="submit"` you can use `type="text"` or any other input type according to your requirement.

Comment: Yes so I am not concern for type in the input field but this is type = 'submit' input field which is never declared readonly but some how it get readonly only css from css files. simple coclusion: readonly not given to this input field but still it run css for given on the readonly attributes(input:read-only).